# noob learning android development... need suggestions

Tags: android

i want to learn android development and have started with something basic like switching windows, alertdialog and such.

next lesson i want to take is something that involves client/server database application. for starters, i will have to create a guest book website (please advice what i should use for server database and scripting language ie.. php/mysql, asp/msaccess). i have extensive knowledge with oracle database and oracle apex but not sure if this will be supported in android.

anyways, the android app that i want to develop will basically sync with the server database and download messages into the phone and displays them in a listview.

this should do for now.

please give me some tips on how to do this.

thanks
ads

Answer (score 3):

To begin with android development, go to this [developer's guide](http://developer.android.com/guide/index.html). This is the best place to start learning Android development.

After that, if you like to read books then you can go to this [book site](http://commonsware.com/). You can find three books here, and the guy that wrote these books are pretty active on SO also(click on the android tag and then go to the top user list, you will see him at the top).

Also, try searching SO first before asking a question. Many users have asked this type of question before. Some references are given below -

1. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1114287/good-book-for-beginning-android-development
2. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/475152/how-can-i-learn-android
3. [Learning Android dev due to curiosity](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4103924/learning-android-dev-due-to-curiosity)
4. [How to go about learning the android framework](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3763301/how-to-go-about-learning-the-android-framework)
5. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4306663/which-book-is-the-best-for-android-self-learning

Best of luck :-) .

**Edit**

From the documentation -

```
Android provides several options for you to save persistent application data. 
The solution you choose depends on your specific needs, such as whether the data 
should be private to your application or accessible to other applications (and the user) 
and how much space your data requires. 

Your data storage options are the following: 
    1.Shared Preferences
        Store private primitive data in key-value pairs. 
    2.Internal Storage
        Store private data on the device memory. 
    3.External Storage
        Store public data on the shared external storage.
    4.SQLite Databases
        Store structured data in a private database.
    5.Network Connection
        Store data on the web with your own network server.
```

To read more, go [here](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html).

Also from the documentation -

`Android provides full support for SQLite databases. Any databases you create will be accessible by name to any class in the application, but not outside the application.`

[Here](http://www.hassanpur.com/blog/?p=27) is an example of an Android client-server model. PHP is used in this example as scripting language.

Also, see the below question -

1. [Options for Client Server Communication in Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1690229/options-for-client-server-communication-in-android)

Comment: hi. thanks for the reply. while those links are very informative, none of them seems to have the information that i'm looking for. i'm not actually asking for codes or anything, just tips. like for example, if i wanted to develop a server/client database app, do i need to use any specific database for my server? any specific scripting language? and on my android app, do i need to learn any specific type of view? how does the android app communicate with the server database? something like that.

Comment: the Android Development: Implementing a simple Client-Server model article was great. it gave me an idea how to fetch data from the server. thank you so much.

Answer (score 0):

Noobism is a relative term. Anyways from what you want to learn, I suggest that you buy Hello Android. Its not a very fancy book, but excellent to get started. (and stay away from android documentation until you get comfortable with general android development)

Comment: thanks for the reply. but do you have something that will help me with the specifics of what i wan't to do.

Comment: What you want to do is quite simple. If you want to stop with this application, then there is not much android development that you need to learn. The best service oriented solution for android has to be a rest based service. If you are comfortable with java then jersey will help you create a simple rest based service. Otherwise the easiest way to create http service layer is thro php. Once the service layer is written, then you just need to learn how to make httpservice call from android. You could get the code directly of the net.

Comment: First google result searching for how to make android http service. http://futureyard.blogspot.com/2009/05/http-get-and-post-thread-service-on.html. Also the book I suggested has a chapter on it.

Comment: thanks. i'll be checking up on http service.

Comment: -1 for `stay away from android documentation`

Comment: @Falmarri, did you read thro the question. He mentioned that he is new to programming in android and he had a simple use case, he does not have to read thro documentation explaining all the various components available to him in android. And did you have the time to read the entire sentence "until you get comfortable with general android development".

Answer (score 0):

[TheNewBoston](http://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PL34F010EEF9D45FB8) on youtube contains over 200 hours of android application development tutorials.